# How to ensure a url is called from my application and not manually from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that contains a button, on click of this button, it will open a browser window using a URL with querystring parameters (the url of a page that i am coding).

Is there a way to ensure that the URL is coming from my application and only from my application - and not just anyone typing the URL manually in a webbrowser?

If not, what is the best way to ensure that a specific URL is coming from a specific application - and not just manually entered in the address bar or a web browser-

Im using asp.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the request was made from one of the pages of your application using:

`Request.UrlReferrer.Contains("mywebsite.com")`

That's the simple way.

The secure way is to put a cookie on the client containing a value encrypted using a secure key or hashed using a secure salt. If the cookie is set to expire when the page is closed it should be impossible for someone to forge.

Here's an example:

On the pages that would redirect to the page you are trying to protect:

```
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SecureCheck");
  //don't set the cookie's expiration so it's deleted when the browser is closed
  cookie.Value = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Session.SessionID, "SHA1");
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

On the page you are trying to protect:

```
  //check to see if the cookie is there and it has the correct value
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["SecureCheck"]) || System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Session.SessionID, "SHA1") != Request.Cookies["SecureCheck"])
    throw Exception("Invalid request. Please access this page only from the application.");
  //if we got this far the exception was not thrown and we are safe to continue
  //insert whatever code here
```

Comment: If the URL is called from an application then the referer will be empty. However that doesn't mean that the application launched it - e.g. it's also empty if the user just opens a new tab and enters the URL.

Comment: Pretty easy to forge and it's not required for a browser to send it, you might easily prevent someone legitimately using the application from performing the action.

Comment: Using a secure cookie is a really good idea, but it won't prevent an authorized user from simply typing in the URL.  The cookie would be sent with that request as well.  Depending on whether the cookie is persistent or not, they may not even need to have the application open at the time (e.g., they might be able to access via a bookmark later).

Comment: @tvanfosson: changed the text to reflect your advice.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use such a cookie please in asp.net

Comment: I've edited the response to have the example code for the cookie thing

Comment: @linkerro thanks, ill try it, however,  is it possible in case the calling application is a windows forms application( and what about a oracle forms application)?

Comment: Not really. You would need a different way to show the application that you have a trusted request, such as a token based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reliable way to do this for a GET request, nor is their any reason to try for a legitimate user.  What you should do instead is ensure that regardless of where the request comes from the user has the proper permissions and access rights and that the session is protected appropriately (HTTP only cookies, SSL, etc.) If the request is changing data, then it should be a POST, not a GET, and it should be accompanied by some suitable cross-site request forgery prevention techniques (such as a cookie containing a nonce that is verified against a matching nonce on the form itself).

Comment: can you please give an example of this cookie please in c#?

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC AntiForgeryToken and related helpers are one example of how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, other than rejecting the request if it doesn't contain a previously generated random one-time token in the parameters (that would be stored in the session, for example).

Comment: can you please give an example using c#?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no  100% secure way to do this, what I am suggesting might at least take care of your basic needs.

This is what you can do .

Client: Add a HTTP header with an encoded string that is like  hash (sha256) of some word.
Then make your client always do a POST request instead of GET.
Server: Check the HTTP Header for encoded string. Also make sure it is a POST request.

This is not 100% as ofcourse someone smart enough could figure out and still generate a request, but depending on your need you might find this enough or not

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referer, the user agent, add an additional header to the request, always do post requests to that url. However, considering HTTP is transmitted in plain text, somebody is always able to let wireshark or fiddler run, capture the HTTP packets and recreate the requests with your measures in place.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters from your application so that you can verify on the server side.

I suggest you use an encryption algorithm and generate random text using a password(key). Then, decrypt the param on the server side and check if it matches your expectation.

I am not very clear though. sorry about that, If had to do something like this, then, I would do something similar to mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to check the header on MVC controller like `Request.Headers["Accept"];` if it is coming from your code in angularjs or jquery:

sample angularjs like this:

```
var url = ServiceServerPath + urlSearchService + '/SearchCustomer?input=' + $scope.strInput;

$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },.....
```

And on the MVC [HttpGet] Action method

```
        [HttpGet]
        [PreventDirectAccess]//It is my custom filters
        // ---> /Index/SearchCustomer?input={input}/
        public string SearchCustomer(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                var isJsonRequestOnMVC = Request.Headers["Accept"];//TODO: This will check if the request comes from MVC else comes from Browser
                if (!isJsonRequestOnMVC.Contains("application/json")) return "Error Request on server!";

                var serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                ISearch customer = new SearchCustomer();
                IEnumerable<ContactInfoResult> returnSearch = customer.GetCustomerDynamic(input);

                return serialize.Serialize(returnSearch);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```